# Awaiting EIC Decision for more than 1 month

Tags: peer-review, journals, rejection, special-issue

I have submitted a paper in a journal's **special issue**. In the first notification, I got a **major revision**. After submitting the revision it goes through (**awaiting for reviewer selection -> awaiting for reviewer scores -> awaiting for editors decision -> Awaiting EIC Decision**). Now, it's in the "**Awaiting EIC Decision**" for more than one month.

Is it a bad sign? Is it ok if I send them an email? I need your opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like). You're at the "Editorial Decision" stage, and as you can see from there, the typical duration is a few workdays to a week. So more than 1 month is definitely atypical, and you should write in and ask.

If you're wondering, there's a good chance the abnormal wait time is because there's more than one "editor-in-chief": the original editor-in-chief, and the editor(s) in charge of the special issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is there anything to do with being special issue?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're asking if it being a special issue has anything to do with the extra time taken, I'd guess yes, for reasons already given above. It's quite possible though that it's for some other reason (e.g. the EiC is ill).